# Why designating 'None' to the node using recursive function while node=None doesn't work?

Tags: python, binary-tree

I want to delete leaf nodes in the binary tree. The following code,

```
def delete_node(node):
if node:
    if not node.left and not node.right:
        return None
    else:
        node.left=delete_node(node.left)
        node.right=delete_node(node.right)
        return node
else:
    return None
```

worked. But directly designating 'None' to the node(node=None) does not worked. What is the difference?

Comment: Your conditional should be indented.